# Is deleting old branches in Git submodules safe w.r.t. usable history of 'supermodules'?

Tags: git, git-submodules

If I use a workflow like this:

- **app_repo** and **app2_repo** have a common submodule, **library_repo**.
- In **library_repo**, I make a **library_feature** branch to work on a new feature while leaving **master** stable.
- **app2_repo** needs the new feature, so I track the submodule development in it (i.e. I update the submodule reference as commits are made to **library_repo**).  In tandem to this, changes are being made to the **app2_repo** source too (the app is under development also).
- After the feature is finished, I merge the **library_feature** branch in **library_repo** back into  **library_repo**'s **master** branch.
- Deveopment continues, with **app2_repo** now inluding **library_repo**'s **master** again.
- I delete **library_repo**'s **library_feature** branch, now that the history is merged into **master**, to keep things 'clean'.

Have I just lost the ability to check out historic **app2_repo** SHAs and have 'submodule update' update correctly with the relevant historical commits from **library_repo**, because I deleted the **library_feature** branch that they were in, or will all the relevent commits still be there, because the history is now shared with **master** now it's merged?

Comment: Interesting question... I would expect it to still work, but the submodule part does add a much more complex level... Does the repo store the info it needs, or does it always ask the submodule? This shouldn't be all that hard to test; it just might take a few minutes (which I don't have right now :p) - you'd probably also want to make sure you do a `git gc` after removing the library_feature branch - not sure if that would affect it, but might be better to be safe...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the relevant commits will still be there.

When you create a commit with a submodule at a particular version, the only information stored in the tree of the "supermodule" is the object name (i.e. SHA1sum) of the commit that the submodule should be at.  So, deleting the branch once it's been merged into master will make no difference - all your old commits in the supermodule will point to the object names of commits that are still in the history of master in the submodule.

If you had deleted a branch which isn't merged into some other branch, the unmerged commits on that branch would eventually be garbage collected and that might create the problem you're worried about, but you've explicitly said here that everything was merged before deleting the branch.